# Why is there a dark spot on my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have corrected normals and cleaned up but there's this weird spot that appears to be dark and a bit wrinkled?

[image: head mesh showing blemish on cheek]

Comment: maybe overlapping vertices or inner faces?

Answer (score 1):

Check the geometry near that dark area (holes, faces inside the head and other weird geometry inside the head, near that area).

Try also the `Merge -> By Distance` with the vertices in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the way to fix this involves the normals. Go to edit mode, select everything, press “Alt N” and go to “Average” and choose “Face Area”. Fixed

Comment: The admins deleted my thought process ‍♂️But that’s how to do it.

Comment: yeah the normals answer worked on my mesh issue. It looked like there was a small mask on the face of my mesh or a bump which would go away after smoothing in sculpt mode, but as soon as I switched to edit or object mode all the smoothing would disappear and there it was the bump back again, of course it had ta be the **flippin normals**. Thanks, Ted Fogg. Twisted Monk >,..,<